# Wubi not downloading ISO

Tags: wubi

A serious problem is occurring  in installing Ubuntu on Windows platform. I have downloaded the "**wubi**" file from official site. But it does not download the ISO image file.

Comment: You can download the ISO separately, and then use it with wubi. For more info, please see [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F).

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1):

Wubi does not come as an .iso file but as a *windows executable* (.exe).

Since you said "It does not download the ISO image file" I presume you did not download wubi but the release file in an .iso to be burnt to a CD or USB. You can download wubi directly from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe).

The .exe file will guide you through the installation process and all you will have to do is restart your computer and select Ubuntu from the boot menu. However notice that Wubi installs Ubuntu inside your existing windows partition and not in a separate one. To have more control of your Ubuntu system I recommend installing it directly from the .iso file. In case you do not know how to burn an .iso to a USB or CD, follow these tutorials:

[-> 4 ways to create bootable USB drives in Windows, Linux & Mac](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/04/4-ways-to-create-bootable-live-usb.html)

[-> Burn a CD or DVD from an .iso file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file)

Then all you will have to do is restart your computer and select the USB/CD from the boot process screen.